# Exception Handling In DataBlocks

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I am trying to understand exception handling in TPL.

The following code seems to swallow exceptions:

```
var processor = new ActionBlock<int>((id) => SomeAction(id), new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { ... });


async Task SomeAction(int merchantID)
{
    //Exception producing code
    ...
}
```

And listening to `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` events does not receive anything either.

So, does this mean the action block does a try-catch in itself when running the actions?

Is there any official documentation of this somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

The exception handling behavior of DataFlow blocks is explained in [Exception Handling in TPL DataFlow Networks](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/exception-handling-in-tpl-dataflow-networks/)

**Original

This code doesn't swallow exceptions. If you await the block to complete with `await processor.Completion` you'll get the exception. If you use a loop to pump messages to the block before calling `Complete()` you need a way to stop the loop too. One way to do it is to use a `CancellationTokenSource` and signal it in case of exception:

```
void SomeAction(int i,CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
    try
    {
        ...
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        //Log the error then
        cts.Cancel();
       //Optionally throw
    }
}
```

The posting code doesn't have to change all that much, it only needs to check whether

```
var cts=new CancellationTokenSource();
var token=cts.Token;
var dopOptions=new new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { 
                           MaxDegreeOfParallelism=10,
                           CancellationToken=token
};
var block= new ActioBlock<int>(i=>SomeAction(i,cts),dopOptions);

while(!token.IsCancellationRequested && someCondition)
{
    block.Post(...);
}
block.Complete();
await block.Completion;
```

When the action throws, the token is signaled and the block ends. If the exception is rethrown by the action, it will be rethrown by `await block.Completion` as well.

If that seems convoluted, it's because that's somewhat of an edge case for blocks. DataFlow is used to create pipelines or networks of blocks.

**The general case**

The name [Dataflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dataflow) is significant.
Instead of building a program by using methods that call each other, you have processing blocks that pass messages to each other. There's no parent method to receive results and exceptions. The pipeline of blocks remains active to receive and process messages indefinitely, until some external controller tells it to stop, eg by calling `Complete` on the head block, or signaling the CancellationToken passed to each block.

A block shouldn't allow unhandled exceptions to occur, even if it's a standalone ActionBlock. As you saw, unless you've already called `Complete()` and `await Completion`, you won't get the exception.

When an unhandled exception occurs inside a block, the block enters the faulted state. That state propagates to all downstream blocks that are linked with the `PropagateCompletion` option. *Upstream* blocks aren't affected, which means they may keep working, storing messages in their output buffers until the process runs out of memory, or deadlocks because it receives no responses from the blocks.

**Proper Failure Handling**

The block should catch exceptions and decide what to do, based on the application's logic:

1. Log it and keep processing. That's not that different from how web application's work - an exception during a request doesn't bring down the server.
2. Send an error message to another block, explicitly. This works but this type of hard-coding isn't very dataflow-ish.
3. Use message types with some kind of error indicator. Perhaps a `Success` flag, perhaps an `Envelope<TMessage>` object that contains either a message or an error.
4. Gracefully cancel the entire pipeline, by signaling all blocks to cancel by signaling the `CancellationTokenSource` used to produce the `CancellationToken`s used by all blocks. That's the equivalent of `throw` in a common program.

#3 is the most versatile option. Downstream blocks can inspect the Envelope and ignore or propagate failed messages without processing. Essentially, failed messages bypass downstream blocks.

[image]

Another option is to use the `predicate` parameter in `LinkTo` and send failed messages to a logger block and successful messages to the next downstream block. In complex scenarios, this could be used to eg retry some operations and send the result downstream.

These concepts, and the image, come from Scott Wlaschin's [Railway Oriented Programming](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/)

Answer (score 1):

The [`TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception) event is not a reliable/deterministic way to handle exceptions of faulted tasks, because it's delayed until the faulted task is cleaned up by the garbage collector. And this may happen long after the error occurred.

The only type of exception that is swallowed by the dataflow blocks is the `OperationCanceledException` ([by design](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29619)). All other exceptions result to the block transitioning to a faulted state. A faulted block has its [`Completion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.idataflowblock.completion) property (which is a `Task`) faulted as well (`processor.Completion.IsFaulted == true`). You can attach a continuation to the `Completion` property, to receive a notification when a block fails. For example you could ensure that an exception will not pass unnoticed, by simply crashing the process:

```
processor.Completion.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => throw t.Exception);
}, default, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

This works because throwing an unhandled exception on the `ThreadPool` causes the application to terminate (after raising the [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception) event).

If your application has a GUI (WinForms/WPF etc), then you could throw the exception on the UI thread, that allows more graceful error handling:

```
var uiContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
processor.Completion.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    uiContext.Post(_ => throw t.Exception, null);
}, default, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

This will raise the [`Application.ThreadException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception) event in WinForms.